# get the logits at each iteration of sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

Is there a way to print the logits at each iteration of `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression` ?

`model = LogisticRegression(max_iter=600).fit(x_vectors, y)`